# Transparent Gradient (or BackgroundImg) in UITabBar like Klarna App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, uitabbar

I have a `UITabbar` in my app. I would like to have it style as it does in the Klarna app. have already tried a background Image to refuse, however, there is the part of the actually should be transparent, always only black. To make it the same on as many devices as possible, it would be better to do this with code rather than with a background image. Can you help me, find nothing about it :(

Here are my try and a Screenshot from the Klarna APP

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD3oC.jpg

Comment: A transparency gradient would be a _mask_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for adding Blur Effect,

```
extension UIImageView
{
    func addBlurEffect()
    {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.extraLight)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds

        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a custom TabBar by yourself for this.

Something like :

```
class TabBarView: UIView{


var curvedShape = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientPath = UIBezierPath()


var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout() // Use CollectionView to populate your tabBar items
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    gradientPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: self.bounds)
    curvedShape.frame = self.bounds
    curvedShape.colors = [UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:1.0).cgColor, UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:0).cgColor]
    curvedShape.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    curvedShape.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.layer.addSublayer(curvedShape)


    // initiate your collectionView here according to your requirement and populate it with the required tabbar items

}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

The result you receive will be something like : 
[image]

The blue view items will be your main collectionView in the controller, the green ones will be your tabBar items, which in your case are images with transparent background.

---

**Edit:**

If you prefer to use UITabBar itself and not your custom view (I don't know why you would restrict yourself with that)

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clear


    return true
}
```

Subclass your UITabBarController as below:

```
import UIKit

class GradientTabBarController: UITabBarController {

let layerGradient = CAGradientLayer()
var curvedShape = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientPath = UIBezierPath()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    gradientPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 200, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 200))
    curvedShape.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 200, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 200)
    curvedShape.colors = [UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:1.0).cgColor, UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:0).cgColor]
    curvedShape.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    curvedShape.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(curvedShape, at: 1)
}
}
```

Output:

Just add your icons to the tabBar as usual after this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have a UITabBarController with four views. How can i implement the TabBar in your Example in my Project? I am a very beginner. This is my Project: https://imgur.com/a/tt6v0q6

Comment: Edited answer. I would still suggest you to use a custom TabBar. This would make it easier for you in the long run.